# Why do we extend JpaRepository Interface and not implements it

Tags: java, jpa, interface, spring-data-jpa, extends

`TestRepository ***extends*** JpaRespotiroy<Test,Long>`

JpaRepository is an interface. Why do we extend it and not implement it as we know in Java? As far as I know, interfaces are implemented, not extended.

Can somebody explain to me please?

Comment: One interface cannot *implement* another. An interface *extends* another interface, but a class *implements* an interface.

Comment: @ernest_k Why don't you add this as the answer?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I only added a likely correct guess. The question doesn't show that `TestRepository` is indeed an interface.

Comment: @ernest_k Of course it does, unless the code doesn't compile.

Comment: If I have read it correctly, the question is about why not define classes using the interfaces. I am new to Spring, and have to learn a lot. As far as  I understood, Spring has a backstage machinery that creates anonymous classes from interfaces in the backstage -- either in the runtime, or using annotations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your code looks like

```
interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long>
```

So TestRepository is an interface and interfaces can extend other interfaces not implement interfaces.

The TestRepository will be implemented from Spring Data JPA during runtime based on the SimpleJpaRepository

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java

Answer (score 4):

In Java

1. Class extends Class 
      `class Test Extends Thread`
2. interface Extend interface 
       `public interface TestI extends Runtime`
3. class implements interface 
     `public class Test implements Runnable`